# how to update the page content without refresh the page by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

the page url is   `http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>`

there are some contents on the page:

```
<div><a href="http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1a">price </a></div>
        <div> the content....</div>
```

if i click the price, the content will be arranged according to the price with  ascending.

```
<div><a href="http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1d">price </a></div>
        <div> the content....</div>
```

if i click the price, the content will be arranged according to the price with descending.

now, i want to get when the visitor click the `price` text, the content arranged can be exchanged. the default state is ascending. and don't refresh the page.

how should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Can use [JQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to assign the html from the url without reloading the page.
On the click the on the price link you can load the content div.

e.g.

```
$('#content_div').load($('#a_price').attr('href'));
```

For html below -

```
<a id="1d" href="example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1d">1d</a>
<a id="1a" href="example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1a">1a</a>
<div id="productListing" />
```

Javascript -

```
$('#1d, #1a').click(function(event){
    // Prevent default link behaviour
    event.preventDefault();
    // load the div contents from the link
    $('#producListing').load(this.attr('href'));
})
```

Have added the ids to the link. Can be made generic.
Also, the link contents should render partial content only with the results, which you would need to display.

Comment: Just be sure to give your content div the id of 'content_div' that this answer suggests.

Comment: Jayendra ,i am sorry i still don't know how to do it. if all the content are in the ID productListing,$("#productListing").load($('#a_price').attr('href'); there are two URL(<a href="http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1d">, <a href="http://example.com/index.php?main_page=index&Path=<?php echo $_GET['Path'];?>&sort=1a">) how to write it? thank you